# Simple app in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am new in Ember and trying to create a simple application based on the tutorial provided by Ember website and videos.

In the sample below I would like to display two tabs Tab1 and Tab2; when switching to Tab1 it should have "Jan" and "Feb"; when switching to Tab2 it should have "Mar" and "Apr". I can switch between tabs but there is no content in any of them, there are no errors in the console. 
Please help me understand why the tab content is empty. 
Thanks!

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-    icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>{{#link-to 'tab1'}}Tab1{{/link-to}}</li>
          <li>{{#link-to 'tab2'}}Tab2{{/link-to}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="tab1">
      <p>{{field1}}</p>
      <p>{{field2}}</p>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="tab2">
    <p>{{field3}}</p>
    <p>{{field4}}</p>  
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-v1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-v1.6.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/0.3.1/showdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.1.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

var tab1 = {
  field1: "Jan",
  field2: "Feb"
};

var tab2 = {
  field3: "Mar",
 field4: "Apr"
};

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('tab1');
  this.resource('tab2');
});

App.tab1Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return tab1;
  }
});

App.tab2Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
   return tab2;
  }
});
```

Comment: do you have any errors in console? can you give us a link to jsbin or something with working code?

Comment: no errors in the console, I can switch between tabs but there is no content in any of them. Sorry, I cant give you a link to the code.

Comment: ok. I don't think you can arbitrarily define variables and return them from the model hook.  You need to define the model *inside* the model hook, or a controller, or as Fixture data in a model class.  I suppose you *could* find a way to do it your way.. but it is breaking away from the way Ember does it.. so you won't be able to find much help doing it that way.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, but could you please modify the code to help me understand? this application was created based on ember "Bloggr" example by Tom Dale (there is a video on youtube).

Comment: unrelated question: why this question is voted -3 already ??? people just vote down instead of answering???

Comment: @kranya I don't understand why it was downvoted either-  Don't be discouraged by the haters and keep posting on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember conventions mandate the name of the classes for your routes.  Your Route classes must be named `App.Tab1Route` and `App.Tab2Route`, not `App.tab1Route` and `App.tab2Route`.  The case of the class names is important.

The rest of your code seems fine!